# ¿Se puede usar HttpRequestBase en Dart/Flutter?

Tags: java, flutter, dart

Estoy intentando hacer este código Java en Dart/Flutter. Es una conexion **HttpRequestBase** de una librería llamada **implementation "cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.2"**.

Ejemplo Java: Dentro de una actividad llamada HttpPut.java hay una llamada a esta librería. Aquí dejo la parte en concreto que quiero llevar a Dart.

```
protected HttpRequestBase getRequestBase(Request request) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.methods.HttpPut httpPost = new cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.methods.HttpPut(
                request.getResource()
        );
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(request.getParameters(), "UTF-8");
        entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"));
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        return httpPost;
    }
```

La clase **Request** contiene lo siguiente:

```
import java.util.Collection;

public interface Request {
    String getResource();

    String getParameters();

    Collection<String> getHeaders();
}
```

Lo que he intentado en Dart es llamar a la librería **http: ^0.12.1** pero no es exactamente lo que necesito. Porque aunque puedo hacer, en este caso httpPut(...), no puedo realizar los pasos siguientes como son **StringEntity**. ¿Como solucionaría esos problemas?

----RESUELTO

Lo he resuelto con el httpClient aquí dejo el link: https://pub.dev/packages/http_client

Para el ejemplo que he puesto anteriormente se haría de la siguiente forma

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'Request.dart';
import 'BaseHttp.dart';

class HttpPut extends BaseHttp {
    HttpPut(int timeoutInMilliseconds) : super(timeoutInMilliseconds);

    Future<HttpClientRequest> getRequestBase(Request request) async {
      HttpClientRequest httpRequest = await HttpClient().putUrl(Uri.parse(request.getResource()));
      httpRequest.headers.contentType = ContentType('aplication', 'json', charset: 'UTF-8');
      return httpRequest;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de igual manera con `http` , aquí un ejemplo básico:

```dart
  final http.Response response = await http.put(
    'https://tu_url',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      'title': title,
    }),
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 201) {
   final result = json.decode(response.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed');
  }
```

En este caso le estoy enviando un objeto json en el `body` , pero si solo deseas enviarle un raw String pásale directamente el String a `body`.

Comment: Ok, gracias, lo acabo de resolver de otra manera con httpClient, actualizo mi comentario con otro resultado